# qt overloaded qtextstream output operator with iterator

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a two classes - Platform, and PlatformModel.  PlatformModel contains a QVector.

I want to output information about each platform in the vector, so I overloaded the output operator of the Platform class like this:

```
QTextStream &operator <<(QTextStream &outStream, const Platform  &platform);
```

which is defined as:

```
QTextStream &operator <<(QTextStream &outStream, const Platform &platform)
{
   platform.print(outStream);
   return outStream;
}
```

From the PlatformModel object, I iterate through the vector like this:

```
QVector<Platform*>::const_iterator i;
for(i = mPlatforms.begin(); i != mPlatforms.end(); ++i)
{
    if ((*i)->mInclude)
    {
        outStream << (*i);
    }
}
```

The QTextStream is eventually written out to a file, but all I'm getting is the address of the platform objects - the overridden operator<< function is not being called.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deference iterator once more - because vector contains pointers, and iterator is pointer to vector element, i is double pointer.

```
    outStream << *(*i);
```

Should work, or you can iterate through vector using `Q_FOREACH` macro or index for simplicity.